# Get a list of SQL Servers in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, sqlclient, dbproviderfactories

I am trying to get a list of all SQL Server data sources using .NET Core 3.1. I've followed the instructions located [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlclientfactory.cancreatedatasourceenumerator?view=netframework-4.8), but `CanCreateDataSourceEnumerator` always returns false. I've tried two different methods to get the list, but they both fail at the if statement.

```
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
        {
            PropertyInfo dbProviderFactoryProperty = con.GetType().GetProperty("DbProviderFactory", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            var factory = dbProviderFactoryProperty.GetValue(con) as DbProviderFactory;

            if (factory.CanCreateDataSourceEnumerator)
            {
                var instance = factory.CreateDataSourceEnumerator();
                await Task.Run(() => table = instance.GetDataSources());

                foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}\\{1}", row["ServerName"], row["InstanceName"]);
            }
        }

        //DbProviderFactories.RegisterFactory("Microsoft.Data.SqlClient", SqlClientFactory.Instance);
        //var factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("Microsoft.Data.SqlClient");

        //if (factory.CanCreateDataSourceEnumerator)
        //{
        //    var instance = factory.CreateDataSourceEnumerator();
        //    await Task.Run(() => table = instance.GetDataSources());

        //    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        //        Console.WriteLine("{0}\\{1}", row["ServerName"], row["InstanceName"]);
        //}
```

I have added an App.config that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider"
        invariant="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient"
        description="Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider for SQL Server"
        type="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory, Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Look at the document you linked. It's for .net framework. What you are doing is very dated. You should look for .net core 3+ resources. E.g using the appsettings.json. And ihn why the await task.run?

Comment: My big question would be, why? This has pretty much never worked reliably, even on Framework (unless perhaps the corporate network doesn't believe in any kind of firewall at all). It typically takes forever to present the user with an incomplete list of database servers (often an empty one). Simply asking the user to provide exactly the server/instance they want tends to make for a much better experience.

Comment: @JeroenMostert It is in the requirements, so I don't have much say in it. I do have an empty field where the connection text can be entered manually, but they want the selection dropdown to match other products (done in Framework, not Core).

Comment: Well, you can simply go back and inform them .NET Core doesn't support this, and point the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlclientfactory.cancreatedatasourceenumerator?view=netcore-3.1) as proof, or even [the source](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/blob/main/src/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/netcore/src/Microsoft/Data/SqlClient/SqlClientFactory.cs). Either this requirement should be dropped, or .NET Core, or they should pay you a lot more money to port the functionality yourself.

Comment: Alternatively, if the requirement is not so much to support this in full generality, but just to have a list of the (known) company servers, these could be stored in a central location (like a well-known database, or even a text file on a share) and retrieved from there. As a bonus this would also be much faster to retrieve... but it would require maintenance.

Comment: I've given up on this. Instead, I keep the last N used ones in a per-user _most recently used_ cache and present them in a drop-down. You have to type (or most likely copy paste) in a server name once, but after that, the UX is very friendly.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. Since this is just for initial setup, we have decided to require the user to type in the server and database name.

Comment: Any solution to this issue on StackOverflow ? :( it's 2022 now and NET5/6 gives me the same result.. and typing in database names in some config form is no option for us.

Comment: @Goodies As mentioned above this is an unreasonable thing to expect to be able to do on modern networks. See Michael Taylor's reply here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1038244/enumerating-sql-server-instances