# How to get available SQL Servers in .NET 6.0?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net, .net-6.0

We recently upgraded our C# projects from .NET Framework 4.5.2 to .NET 6.0, and now the line

```
System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources()
```

no longer works. As far as I can tell, the class `SqlDataSourceEnumerator` is just not included in the `System.Data` assembly for .NET 6.0.

I've looked online for other ways to get available SQL Servers, but all of ones I've found either recommend using `SqlDataSourceEnumerator`, or `SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers()` which relies on it internally.

What other ways are there to get available SQL Servers in our C# code that are compatible with .NET 6.0? We need a solution that returns the same info as before (including Server, Name, Instance, Version, and IsLocal).

Comment: This might provide some insight and possibly a work around: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67577933/the-name-sqldatasourceenumerator-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context.  This might also be a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66437788/6530134

Comment: @TimothyG. Thanks, I checked them out. Unfortunately they don't work for .NET 6.0. It's starting to look like it won't be implemented, and that a better solution is just to ask the user to type the server they want to connect to, as suggested in the comments to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67235214/get-a-list-of-sql-servers-in-net-core Still, if there's any other workable solution, I'd be happy to hear it.

Comment: Maybe try dbatools, which is a Powershell module, you can use `Find-DbaInstance` which uses a number of different methods to find instances https://docs.dbatools.io/Find-DbaInstance.html